# Can I use Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery UI at the same time?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I want to use an "auto-suggest" which is not available in Bootstrap, whereas jQuery UI has its own methods for auto-suggest.

Can I use both? Will it overload the bandwidth?

Comment: jQuery UI is 6.6k (minified and gzipped) so unless your bandwidth is measured in kb, this won't be a problem.

Comment: Things have changed since I posted this question. Now, there are a lot of Bootstrap plugins which are good enough to replace the existing jQuery UI plugins. Now, I use Bootstrap with plugins made for bootstrap.

Comment: Why not using twitter's typeahead (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) for auto suggest?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Check out [jquery-ui-bootstrap](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap).  From the README:

> Twitter's Bootstrap was one of my favorite projects to come out of
>   2011, but having used it regularly it left me wanting two things:
>
> The ability to work side-by-side with jQuery UI (something which
>   caused a number of widgets to break visually) The ability to theme
>   jQuery UI widgets using Bootstrap styles. Whilst I love jQuery UI, I
>   (like others) find some of the current themes to look a little dated.
>   My hope is that this theme provides a decent alternative for others
>   that feel the same. To clarify, this project doesn't aim or intend to
>   replace Twitter Bootstrap. It merely provides a jQuery UI-compatible
>   theme inspired by Bootstrap's design. It also provides a version of
>   Bootstrap CSS with a few (minor) sections commented out which enable
>   the theme to work along-side it.

Answer (score 62):

just to update this, bootstrap v2 no longer conflicts with jquery ui

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/171

**Edit**: as @Freshblood there are a few things that still conflict. However, as originally posted Twitter suggests that they are working on this and it largely works, specially compared to v1.

Comment: Are you really sure about that ? Still i see a problem with jquery datepicker

Comment: I would suggest you take the bootstrap v2 and jquery ui and create an empty test page to verify that it's not your code. I haven't had a problem since the new version

Comment: Please check this jquery ui datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year . As you can see with this settings datepicker contains dropdownbox element so bootstrap already override all input elements. But there is no any problem if you dont use datepicker with these settings.

Comment: Any widget contains input element will conflict with twitter bootstrap css styles.

Comment: well it's been working for me while I haven't used that specific example. I was also going by what Twitter said them self. I image could could change jquery ui's or the bootstrap css to be more specific.

Comment: Negatory. [Bootstrap's button functions don't work with jQuery UI](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6094) as they both define a `button()` method.

Comment: @BryanH as my edit suggests, it's a **vast** improvement over v1 and I recognize that there at still some issues. They've also fixed most of the *style* conflicts

Answer (score 24):

For future reference (since this is google's top answer ATM), to prevent jQuery UI from overriding bootstrap's or your custom style, you need to create a custom download and select the `no-theme` theme. That will only include jQuery UI's resets, and not overload bootstrap's style for various elements.

While we're at it, some jQuery UI components (such as datepicker) have a native bootstrap implementation. The native bootstrap implementations will use the bootstrap css classes, attributes and layouts, so should have a better integration with the rest of the framework.

Comment: I don't see a no-theme theme here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/.  Did I miss it or is it no longer there?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/download/ is the link you should use. Scroll to the bottom and select "No Theme" in the list.

Answer (score 3):

In my limited experience I am coming across issues as well. It appears that JQuery elements (such as buttons) can be styled using bootstrap CSS. However, I am experiencing issues having created a JQuery UI tab and wanting to lock a bootstrap only input (using the input-append class) to the bottom of each tab, only the first sits correctly. So, JQuery tabs + Bootstrap buttons = probably not.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap still doesnt work with Jquery UI, for example the modal.Bootstrap has nice style but as a framework with Twitter behind isnt that good.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running into javascript namespace collisions, you can use Bootstrap's [`noConflict()`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-noconflict) function make it cede functionality to jQuery UI.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question specifically mentions jQuery-UI autosuggest feature, the question title is more general: does bootstrap 3 work with jQuery UI? I was having trouble with the jQUI datepicker (pop-up calendar) feature. I solved the datepicker problem and hope the solution will help with other jQUI/BS issues.

I had a difficult time today getting the latest jQueryUI (ver 1.12.1) datepicker to work with bootstrap 3.3.7. What was happening is that the calendar would display but it would not close.

Turned out to be a version problem with jQUI and BS. I was using the latest version of Bootstrap, and found that I had to downgrade to these versions of jQUI and jQuery:

jQueryUI - 1.9.2 *(tested - works)*
jQuery - 1.9.1 or 2.1.4 *(tested - both work. Other vers may work, but these work.)*
Bootstrap 3.3.7 *(tested - works)*

Because I wanted to use a custom theme, I also built a custom download of jQUI (removed a few things like all the interactions, dialog, progressbar and a few effects I don't use) -- and made sure to select "Cupertino" at the bottom as my theme.

I installed them thus:

```
<head>
...etc...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css">

<!-- <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.js"></script>
...etc...
</head>
```

For those interested, the CSS folder looks like this:

```
[css]
  - bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css
  - font-awesome.min.css
  - style.css
  - [cupertino]
      - jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css
      [images]
          - ui-bg_diagonals-thick_90_eeeeee_40x40.png
          - ui-bg_glass_100_e4f1fb_1x400.png
          - ui-bg_glass_50_3baae3_1x400.png
          - ui-bg_glass_80_d7ebf9_1x400.png
          - ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f2f5f7_1x100.png
          - etc (8 more files that were in the downloaded jQUI zip file)
```

Answer (score 1):

If don't store it locally and use the link that they provide you might have an improved performance.The client might have the scripts already cached in some cases. As for the case of jQueryUI i would recommend not loading it until necessary. 
They are both minimized, but you can fire up the console and look at the network tab and see how long it takes for it to load, once it is initially downloaded it will be cached so you shouldn't worry afterwards.My conclusion would be yes use them both but use a CDN

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use both. js bootstrap from twitter is a collection of jquery plugins. There shohuldn't be any conflict with jQuery UI.

Regarding bandwidth overload, it really depends on how you handle the requests to load all of your js files. if you really dont want to make multiple requests to the server to request for each file, just append them together and minimize. Or you probably can get rid of some js bootstrap plugins you dont need. it is very modular.

Comment: All the JS is properly namespaced, but it's CSS collisions that you need to worry about: if you include a JUI widget in a Bootstrap tab, what takes precedence?

Comment: It's not just jQuery's CSS that looks bad in Bootstrap. Bootstrap makes sweeping CSS changes, often with `!important`, that I find myself constantly having to override and fix, sometimes with hacky code. I hate Bootstrap and discourage its use, at least until it stops mucking with elements that don't use Bootstrap's classes. (This isn't the original designer's fault—I doubt Twitter's original devs expected what they were working on to become a popular library.)

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI has a nice [bootstrap theme here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap/) and a set of web UI comparable to jquery-UI.
They also have an [open source version](http://www.telerik.com/download/kendo-ui-web-open-source) that works nicely with the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have site developed using jquery ui, I just tried to plug in bootstrap for future development and styling but it breaks virtually everything.

So No they are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is the top result on google on **jquery ui and bootstrap.js** I decided to add this as community wiki.

I am using:

- Bootstrap v3.2.0
- jquery-2.1.0
- jquery-ui-1.10.3

and somehow when I include bootstrap.js it disables the dropdown of the [jquery ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

my three workarounds:

- exclude bootstrap.js
- or more to typeahead lib
- move from bootstrap.js to bootstrap.min.js (strange, but worked for me)

Comment: combination of jquery ui bootstrap also disable tooltip and datepicker.

Answer (score -3):

The data-role="none" is the key to make them work together. You can apply to the elements you want bootstrap to touch but jquery mobile to ignore.
like this 
input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" **data-role="none"**

Comment: this question was about bootstrap and jquery-ui, not jquery mobile