# make bootstrap twitter dialog modal draggable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, draggable

I'm trying to make bootstrap twitter dialog modal draggable with this jquery plugin:

http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag#demos

but it doesn't work.

```
var $div = $('html');
console.debug($('.drag'));
$('#modalTest')
    .drag("start", function(ev, dd) {
        dd.limit = $div.offset();
        dd.limit.bottom = dd.limit.top + $div.outerHeight() - $(this).outerHeight();
        dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth();
    })
    .drag(function(ev, dd) {
        $(this).css({
            top: Math.min(dd.limit.bottom, Math.max(dd.limit.top, dd.offsetY))
            , left: Math.min(dd.limit.right, Math.max(dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX))
        });
    });
```

Have you idea how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591597/twitter-bootstrap-modal-form-how-to-drag-and-drop using JQuery UI

Comment: None of the answers below are great because [bootstrap conflicts with jQuery UI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9048214/586086).

Comment: @AndrewMao, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591597/twitter-bootstrap-modal-form-how-to-drag-and-drop/24562349#24562349.

Comment: @AndrewMao my answer is only using jQuery, no pluggin. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51824269/1914034

Answer (score 101):

```
$("#myModal").draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

it works for me. I got it from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591597/twitter-bootstrap-modal-form-how-to-drag-and-drop). if you give me thanks please give 70% to [Andres Ilich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680398/andres-ilich)

Comment: you must do have jquery.ui included, because draggable funciton is from there. :)

Comment: This way implemented dragging works, but is very buggy.

Comment: One of the buggy experiences I had was due to overflow.  A scroll bar was showing as I dragged around the modal.  I set the overflow to hidden on the modal.

Comment: This is working fine for me with jQuery UI and bootstrap

Comment: Jeremy, could you please explain in more details what exactly you did ?)

Comment: It also got work with `ui-bootstrap` angular version, thanks a lot, you saved my day :)

Comment: @IdahoB 's answer worked much better for me, didn't have strange dragging artifacts https://stackoverflow.com/a/39126290/2283261

Comment: For you: Th
For Andres: anks

Comment: Worked on desktop browser, how to make it work on a tab browser? I want to touch on the header and drag.

Comment: I'm using React but this solution worked out great for me thank you!             
    `<Draggable
                    onDrag={this.onDrag}
                    onStop={this.onStop}
                    handle=".modal-header"
                >`

Answer (score 60):

You can use the code below if you dont want to use jQuery UI or any third party pluggin. It's only plain jQuery.

**This answer works well with Bootstrap v3.x . For version 4.x see @User comment below**

```js
$(".modal").modal("show");

$(".modal-header").on("mousedown", function(mousedownEvt) {
    var $draggable = $(this);
    var x = mousedownEvt.pageX - $draggable.offset().left,
        y = mousedownEvt.pageY - $draggable.offset().top;
    $("body").on("mousemove.draggable", function(mousemoveEvt) {
        $draggable.closest(".modal-dialog").offset({
            "left": mousemoveEvt.pageX - x,
            "top": mousemoveEvt.pageY - y
        });
    });
    $("body").one("mouseup", function() {
        $("body").off("mousemove.draggable");
    });
    $draggable.closest(".modal").one("bs.modal.hide", function() {
        $("body").off("mousemove.draggable");
    });
});
```

```css
.modal-header {
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: Best answer. The solution is not depended on jQuery-ui.

Comment: This works but in bootstrap 4 the dialog would jump around a bit when you start dragging. I changed the line `$draggable.closest(".modal-dialog").offset...` to `$draggable.closest(".modal-content").offset...` and now it works correctly.

Answer (score 34):

The top-ranked solution (by Mizbah Ahsan) is not quite right ...but is close.  If you apply draggable() to the modal dialog element, the browser window scroll bars will drag around the screen as you drag the modal dialog.  The way to fix that is to apply draggable() to the modal-dialog class instead:

```
$(".modal-dialog").draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: your solution works perfectly and is best one I have found.

Comment: wonderful workaround for not dragging the scrollbar. I was looking for a solution just like this.

Answer (score 8):

Like others said, the simpliest solution is just call `draggable()` function from *jQuery UI*  just after showing modal:

```
$('#my-modal').modal('show')
              .draggable({ handle: ".modal-header" });
```

But there is a several problems with compatibility between *Bootstrap* and *jQuery UI* so we need some addition fixes in css:

```
.modal
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.modal-dialog{
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.modal-header{      /* not necessary but imo important for user */
    cursor: move;
}
```

Comment: This works great for the dragging but the modals then open against the left margin of the screen.

Answer (score 6):

use the jquery UI draggable, much simpler
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 5):

i did this:

```
$("#myModal").modal({}).draggable();
```

and it make my very standard/basic modal draggable.

not sure how/why it worked, but it did.

Comment: you can add alot of options and events to a singular jquery selection. do .hide() after draggable and it'll hide. I dont think you need the brackets inside the modal options.

Answer (score 3):

For the mouse cursor (with jQuery UI) :

```
$('#my-modal').draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

For the touch cursor (with jQuery):

```
var box = null;
var touchobj = null;
var position = {'x':0, 'y':0};
var positionbox = {'x':0, 'y':0};

// init touch
$('.modal-header').on('touchstart', function(e){
    box = $(this).closest('.modal-dialog');
    touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];

    // take position touch cursor
    position['x'] = touchobj.pageX;
    position['y'] = touchobj.pageY;

    //take original position box to move with touch
    positionbox['x'] = parseInt(box.css('left'));
    positionbox['y'] = parseInt(box.css('top'));

    e.preventDefault();
});

// on move touch
$('.modal-header').on('touchmove', function(e){
    var dist = {'x':0, 'y':0};
    touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];

    // we calculate the distance of move
    dist['x'] = parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - position['x'];
    dist['y'] = parseInt(touchobj.clientY) - position['y'];

    // we apply the movement distance on the box
    box.css('left', positionbox['x']+dist['x'] +"px");
    box.css('top', positionbox['y']+dist['y'] +"px");

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The addition of the 2 solutions is compatible

Answer (score 2):

In my own case, i had to set `backdrop` and set the `top` and `left` properties before i could apply `draggable` function on the modal dialog. Maybe it might help someone ;)

```
if (!($('.modal.in').length)) {       
$('.modal-dialog').css({
     top: 0,
     left: 0
   });
}
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: false,
   show: true
});

$('.modal-dialog').draggable({
  handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am enabling draggable. It works.

```
var bootstrapDialog = new BootstrapDialog({
    title: 'Message',
    draggable: true,
    closable: false,
    size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_WIDE,
    message: 'Hello World',
    buttons: [{
         label: 'close',
         action: function (dialogRef) {
             dialogRef.close();
         }
     }],
});
bootstrapDialog.open();
```

Might be it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI
Just link jquery UI to your project. Little bit of css is needed for removing transition given by bootstrap on "modal-content" element.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<style>
    .modal.fade.ui-draggable-dragging {
        -moz-transition: none;
        -o-transition: none;
        -webkit-transition: none;
        transition: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $('.modal-content').resizable({
        minHeight: 300,
        minWidth: 300
    });
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();
</script>
```