# Twitter Bootstrap Modal Form: How to drag and drop?

Tags: drag-and-drop, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to be able to move around (on the greyed-out background, by dragging and dropping) the modal form that is provided by Bootstrap 2. Can anyone tell me what the best practice for achieving this is?

Comment: See my plain jQuery answer (no 3rd party pluggin or jQuery UI needed) https://stackoverflow.com/a/51824269/1914034

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The bootstrap doesn't come with any dragging and dropping functionality by default, but you can add a little jQuery UI spice into the mix to get the effect you're looking for. For example, using the [`draggable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) interaction from the framework you can target your modal ID to allow it to be dragged around within the modal backdrop.

Try this:

**JS**

```
$("#myModal").draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BV2XA/198/show/), edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BV2XA/198/).

Update: [bootstrap3 demo](http://output.jsbin.com/vafulubaju)

Comment: After set the `.modal-header { cursor: move }` this works like a charm.

Comment: I cant see this working on the last bootstrap version, 3.3.5. Any tips? Changed the Jquery to 1.11.0, but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Khrys, here is an updated demo with the draggable modal header, http://output.jsbin.com/vafulubaju. This answer is pretty old so I'm guessing some JS link in the demo is broken).

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: The demos provided don't don't work. Any chance of an update?

Comment: Added a variant below that attaches globally to all modals.

Answer (score 9):

Whatever draggable option you go for, you might want to turn off the `*-transition` properties for `.modal.fade` in bootstrap’s CSS file, or at least write some JS that temporarily disables them during dragging. Otherwise, the modal doesn’t drag exactly as you would expect.

Comment: this issue discussed and solved at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881245/draggable-js-bootstrap-modal-performance-issues

Answer (score 3):

You can use a little script likes this.

simplified from [Draggable without jQuery UI](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/)

```
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.drags = function (opt) {

            opt = $.extend({
                handle: "",
                cursor: "move"
            }, opt);

            var $selected = this;
            var $elements = (opt.handle === "") ? this : this.find(opt.handle);

            $elements.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function (e) {
                var pos_y = $selected.offset().top - e.pageY,
                  pos_x = $selected.offset().left - e.pageX;
                $(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
                    $selected.offset({
                        top: e.pageY + pos_y,
                        left: e.pageX + pos_x
                    });
                }).on("mouseup", function () {
                    $(this).off("mousemove"); // Unbind events from document                
                });
                e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
            });

            return this;

        };
    })(jQuery);
```

example : $("#someDlg").modal().drags({handle:".modal-header"});

Comment: Your code is outdated. Tried your code and it worked, but dragging is buggy. Fixed it by getting the code from the link above. Please update your code, based from the one from the link.

Answer (score 1):

Building on previous answers utilizing jQuery UI, this, included once, will apply to all your modals and keep the modal on screen, so users don't accidentally move the header off screen so they can no longer access the handle. Also sets the cursor to 'move' for better discoverability.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function(evt) {
    let $modal = $(evt.target);
    $modal.find('.modal-content').draggable({
        handle: ".modal-header",
        containment: $modal
    });
    $modal.find('.modal-header').css('cursor', 'move')
});
```

`evt.target` is the `.modal` which is the translucent overlay behind the actual `.modal-content`.

Answer (score 0):

jquery UI is large and can conflict with bootstrap.

An alternative is DragDrop.js:  http://kbjr.github.io/DragDrop/index.html

```
DragDrop.bind($('#myModal')[0], {
  anchor: $('#myModal .modal-header')
});
```

You still have to deal with transitions, as @user535673 suggests.   I just remove the fade class from my dialog.