# jQuery theme optimized for mobile / tablet?

Tags: jquery-ui, themes

I'm building a web app that should be used on desktop mobile and tablet too. I need the extra widgets of jQuery UI: date picker, resizable , sortable, draggable, etc. These are missing from jQuery mobile, so I cannot use jQuery mobile.

The jQuery UI themes were not designed for tablet / mobile. Buttons, texts, list items and all other widgets are too small to be controlled with a touch screen. Also the stock icons are too small. I know that there is the jquery ui theme roller, but it would take forever to construct some alternative themes that can be used for tablet / mobile. (I would have to create my own stock icons too, with a different size.) I do not want to spend my time creating a theme, because my primary goal is to create a web app that can be used from a mobile or a tablet. Is there a website where I can download mobile optimized jquery ui themes? With much bigger buttons, texts etc. but with all the jquery ui widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery Mobile**

http://jquerymobile.com/  exists

**Twitter**

You may want look into Twitter Bootstrap. It is no jQuery-UI but it is powered by jQuery and can with in conjunction with jQuery-UI so it meets some of your needs.

**Addendum**

DatePicker

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

OR you can use jQuery-UI's date picker

Drag and Drop

[Twitter Bootstrap Modal Form: How to drag and drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591597/twitter-bootstrap-modal-form-how-to-drag-and-drop)

Comment: Bootstrap looks good for me. I'll have to check if I can create/destroy these elements from Javascript though. Thanks.

I don't see any date picker component. No draggable, droppable, and many others are missing. :-(