# how to make modal movable from one end to other end using vue js

Tags: vue.js

Have code like this in vue.js ,my agenda is to make the modal movable from one end to other end, here is my code,have used bootstrap modal for this purpose and have included : draggable

```
<b-modal ref="my-modal" hide-footer title="Edit Record">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="">Viz Attributes</div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
        </div>
    </div>
</b-modal>
```

Comment: Just have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12592150/12057794

Comment: this is using jquery,required is in vue.js,or only using pure bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

you can't position them absolutely in the viewport.

You would need to change the positioning of the modal dialog sub-container to absolute and control the left/top position based on dragging. This is not an overly easy task.  You would need to create your own modal to draggable.
I suggest to you use **Vue.js modal** component  DEMO: www.vue-js-modal.yev.io
install: www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-modal

```html
<modal name="bar" draggable=".window-header">
  <div class="window-header">DRAG ME HERE</div>
  <div>
     Hello!
  </div>
</modal>
```

Draggable property can accept not only Boolean but also String parameters.

Comment: dragging is not happing if i click on "DRAG ME HERE"?

Comment: did you install the component of "Vue.js modal"??