# I want to create a draggable modalDialog in shiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

I want to create a draggable `shiny::modalDialog()` with just `shiny` and JS/jQuery and without other packages like `shinyjqui`.
Following the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591597/twitter-bootstrap-modal-form-how-to-drag-and-drop) it should be easily achievable with the jQuerys `.draggable` sine the `modalDialog` created when clicking on the `actionButton` has bootstrap class `modal`, but somehow it does not work. Does anybody has some advice?

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui = fluidPage(theme = bs_theme(version = 5),

  div(style = "margin: 4rem; display: flex; justify-content: center;",
  div(    
  actionButton(inputId = "action", label = "open modal"))),
  
  
  tagList(
  tags$script(HTML('$(".modal").draggable({
                      handle: ".modal-header"
                      });')))
)

server = function(input, output, session){
 
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        title = "Modal", easyClose = T))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why you can't use a package designed to handle this?

Comment: `draggable` does not belong to jQuery but to **jQuery UI**.

Comment: and that it belongs to jQuery UI qualifies it for that I can not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `shinyjqui` you still need to add `jQuery UI` to use `.draggable`. Additionally to the missing JS library, your code doesn't work because you can not enable draggable functionality to an element that doesn't exist yet. You need to add the JS code just after the creation of the modal inside `showModal`.

```R
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui = fluidPage(theme = bs_theme(version = 5),
   tags$head(tags$script(src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js")),
   div(style = "margin: 4rem; display: flex; justify-content: center;",
       div(    
         actionButton(inputId = "action", label = "open modal"))
       )
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    
    showModal(
      tagList(
        modalDialog(title = "Modal", easyClose = T),
        tags$script(HTML('$(".modal").draggable({
                      handle: ".modal-header"
                      });'))
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It is still possible to use only JS as is described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp).

Comment: Why can't I call `tags$script(HTML('$(".modal").draggable();'))` anywhere other than inside the `tagList`? For instance, why won't `shinyjs::runjs()` work as a separate argument? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a reprex with the `shinyjqui` package. Thanks Dean Attali for the wisdom and knowledgebase.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  showModal(
      shinyjqui::draggableModalDialog()
  )
}
```

shinyApp(ui, server)