# Cakephp jQuery dialog title bar: close button doesn't shows its icon and title

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem with close button of the jquery modal dialog in cakephp.

Dialog is displayed ok. Close button in the title bar is displayed too, but "x" symbol is not displayed, neither is title text of the close button on mouse over.

Here is the code:

In the default.ctp I have

```
...
echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui');
...
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.10.1.min');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom');
...
```

In the view:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" style="display:none"></div>

echo $html->link($a,$href,array('class' => 'modalDlg','id' => "id,'title' => 'Title','escape' => false));
```

and script code:

```
$(".modalDlg").click(function(){
    title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#dialog-modal').load(
    $(this).attr('href'),
    function(){
    $(this).dialog('option','title',title);
    $(this).dialog('option','closeText',CLOSE);
            $(this).dialog("open");
            $(this).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    );
    return false;
});

$(function(){
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
        closeText: "close",
        modal: true
    });
});
```

For testing reasons I have tried to set closeText in the initialization part and in before open, but neither works.

**Update:**

Here is what above jQuery code has produced for the close button:

```
<button class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close"></button>
```

while in the demo code for the jQuery Modal Dialogs the code for the close button looks like this:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
</button>
```

Anybody can help with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Dialog - missing close icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367736/jquery-ui-dialog-missing-close-icon)

Answer (score 0):

If you use twitter bootstrap, try comment the line that you make a bootstrap javascript load.
How I don't use bootstrap functions, It worked fine to me.