# Bootstrap throws Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use Bootstrap to make an interface for a program. I added jQuery 1.11.0 to the `<head>` tag and thought that was that, but when I launch the web page in a browser jQuery reports an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

I have tried using jQuery 1.9.0, I have tried with copies hosted on several CDNs, but I can't get it work. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Include jQuery **before** Bootstrap...

Comment: In my case, I installed jquery before bootstrap and then, it worked fine. Just including before bootstrap didn't solve the error.

Comment: I my case, instead of adding jquery in the footer (as in bootstrap template); I added it in the header. Solved the problem.

Comment: just add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` before the bootstrap import script.

Copy the latest CDN here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery

Comment: Are you using Electron ? I've got the exact same issue while use Electron because jQuery global declaration is done in the module and not the Wndows. Force the declaration to the global windows object instead:
`<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./contents/jquery-3.5.1/jquery-3.5.1.js');</script>
 <script src="./contents/bootstrap-4.5.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
Solution found here: [link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework)

Comment: I understand this post is dated. I found another situation where this error occurs.

In my case, the solution was that in the .aspx source file for each form, I was calling a wrong jquery version:

old code: 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

corrected: 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

Once I made this correction the program runs fine without triggering the jquery error. Need to verify what jquery version you have installed on the application. Another quick piece to check that can cause this error.

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Try this

Change the order of JS files. It should be like below.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have jQuery before Bootstrap and get the error anyway!

Comment: worked but got a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom

Comment: If it's not working from this.. it might be that jQuery is installed via Bower and so you might need to look under bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js   .. the "dist" part being what I had overlooked.

Comment: Worked for me for a Django-Oscar project. This error starting showing up out-of-the-blue. I suppose messing with a completely unrelated code can change the rendering sequence and trigger this error.

Comment: apparently I did not notice I have bootstrap.js included twice - first time it was way before query

Answer (score 114):

If you're in a **Browser-Only environment**, use [SridharR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22658081/112731)'s solution.

If you're in a **Node/CommonJS + Browser environment** (e.g. electron, node-webkit, etc..); the reason for this error is that jQuery's export logic first checks for `module`, not `window`:

```js
if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
    // CommonJS/Node
} else {
    // window
}
```

Note that it exports itself via `module.exports` in this case; so `jQuery` and `$` are not assigned to `window`.

So to resolve this, instead of `<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>`;

Simply assign it yourself by a `require` statement:

```html
<script>
    window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
</script>
```

*NOTE: If your electron app does not need `nodeIntegration`, set it to `false` so you won't need this workaround.*

Comment: ```window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');``` this worked for me attempting to assemble a brunch build with jQuery 2 and Bootstrap 3. Only took me several hours to find your answer though :(. Does this requirement change in later versions of jQuery?

Comment: I don't know but since this is not a bug, I don't think so. If your electron app does not need `nodeIntegration`, set it to `false` so you won't need this workaround.

Comment: You have to install jquery using `npm install jquery` not with bower.

Comment: Useful to see how electron deals with the libraries different than a window based app

Comment: I still don't understand it, but Laravel uses the same approach: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.7.0/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L12

Comment: must be multiple things that caused this error because when i added your solkution i got "require is not defined".

Answer (score 17):

You should load jQuery first because Bootstrap use jQuery features. Like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/animate.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        
<!--   Shuffle your scripts HERE  -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<!--   End  -->   

        <title>pyMeLy Interface</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="title1"><strong>pyMeLy</strong></p>
        <p class="title2"><em> A stylish way to view your media</em></p>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Movies</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to add JQuery before adding bootstrap-

```
<!-- JQuery Core JavaScript -->
<script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have provided wrong order for JAVASCRIPT and BOOTSTRAP

by convention bootstrap must follow jquery file definition

```
<!-- JQuery Core JavaScript -->
<script src="lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="lib/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case solution is really silly, and strange.

Below code was pre-populated by _Layout.cshtml file. (NOT written by me)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But, when I verified in Scripts folder, jquery-1.10.2.min.js was not even available. Hence, replaced code like below where jquery-1.9.1.min.js is an existing file:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this problem I took three steps:

1. Use jQuery versions anywhere between 1.9.0 and 3.0.0
2. Declare the jQuery file before declaring the Bootstrap file
3. Declare these two script files at the bottom of the `<body></body>` tags   rather than in the `<head></head>`.
   These worked for me but there may be different behaviors based on the browser you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NodeJS and got the same error. Like the other answers, the problem was also because JQuery needed to be loaded before Bootstrap; however, because of the NodeJS characteristics, this change had to be aplied in the **pipeline.js file**.

The change in pipeline.js was like this:

```
var jsFilesToInject = [
  // Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
  'js/dependencies/angular.1.3.js',
  'js/dependencies/jquery.js',
  'js/dependencies/bootstrap.js',
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',
];
```

I'm also using grunt to help, and it automatically changed the order in the main html page:

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!-- other dependencies -->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

Hope it helps! You didn't said what your environment was, so I decided to post this answer.

Answer (score 1):

On official docs:
https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron

```
<head>
  <script>
  window.nodeRequire = require;
  delete window.require;
  delete window.exports;
  delete window.module;
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I fixed it on angular.json with the code " "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `require.js` than need to add 
`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')` in app.js

OR
you can make dependent file load after parent file loaded.. such as below concept

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "scripts/appScript",
    paths: {
        'jquery':'jQuery/jquery.min',
        'bootstrap':'bootstrap/bootstrap.min' 
    },
   shim
    shim: {
        'bootstrap':['jquery'],
        },

    // kick start application
    deps: ['app']
});
```

Above code shown that `bootstrap` is dependent on `Jquery` so i have added in `shim` and make it dependent

Answer (score 0):

If your code looks good, verify that jQuery successfully loaded to your server. In my case, the jQuery files were published to the server by my IDE, but the web server only had a 0 KB file stub. With no content, the server failed to serve the file to the browser.

After re-publishing the file and verifying that the server actually received the whole file, then my web page stopped giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JQuery js before adding bootstrap js file, because BootStrap use jqueries function. So make sure to load first jquery js and then bootstap js file.

```
<!-- JQuery Core JavaScript -->
<script src="app/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="app/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs IE intranet only, check compatibility settings and uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility mode" .

IE-->settings-->compatibility

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had tried almost all the above methods.

Finally fixed it by including the

```
script src="{%static 'App/js/jquery.js' %}"
```

just after loading the staticfiles i.e `{% load staticfiles %}` in base.html