# Animsition and Wow JS

Tags: javascript, ios, animate.css, wow.js, animsition

I’ve created a new version of [my website](http://gillesnolorgues.com). 
 I have two problems with the final version.

**First problem:**
To sum up, I use the [Animsition](http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/) plugin to start the CSS fade transition between pages and when I scroll, I use the [WOW](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) library and [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to start the CSS fadeup on my pictures.

My problem, when the page is loaded for the first time, the CSS fadeup have already started. It works perfectly when the page has already been loaded.
May be, is it a problem with the JS code? I don’t find the solution.

**Second problem:**

It’s about the image hover effects on iOS, I have to tape twice on the screen to start the image link and I would like to tape one.

Many thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

On Console I have Seen This Error

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

**Try this**

Change the order of files it should be like below..

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
```

**Reference :**
[Bootstrap won't detect jQuery 1.11.0 - Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658015/bootstrap-wont-detect-jquery-1-11-0-uncaught-error-bootstraps-javascript-re)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's true, i didn't see this bug but i've always the CSS fadeup which start before the page is loaded for the first time.