# Bootstrap dropdown list button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

When click on bootstrap button a list should be opened, but it doesn't respond on the click.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">test</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fanadka/r0sfvrcz/

Any idea?

Comment: in addition to @adeneo solution, we should change the order of the files as below:
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'></script>

<!-- bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

instead of having bootstrap before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658015/bootstrap-wont-detect-jquery-1-11-0-uncaught-error-bootstraps-javascript-re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to include jQuery in your fiddle.

Secondly, you're missing the connection between the button and the dropdown, you'll should add an ID and some aria tags, like this

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">test</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" id="mydp" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" >
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="mydp">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r0sfvrcz/4/)