# I'm trying to use the menu bar from bootstrap but I'm getting the error message: requires jquery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new in bootstrap and web development. I'm trying to configure the menu bar using bootstrap, but I'm getting this error message:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>       at

My header is like this:

```
<meta charset=amp;quot;utf-8amp;quot;>
<meta http-equiv=amp;quot;X-UA-Compatibleamp;quot; content=amp;quot;IE=edgeamp;quot;>
<meta name=amp;quot;viewportamp;quot; content=amp;quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1amp;quot;>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
```

Could you please help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first <script> containing bootstrap comes before you include jquery, which is what causes the error. You're also including bootstrap multiple times, and different versions. Decide which version you want to use and then include just that one, after bringing in jquery. For example you can get rid of the line with 4.0.0-alpha.5 in it, and the 2nd to last line (the local js/bootstrap.min.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks similar to this problem: [Bootstrap won't detect jQuery 1.11.0 - Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658015/bootstrap-wont-detect-jquery-1-11-0-uncaught-error-bootstraps-javascript-re)

As @jeff_carey has mentioned, you have multiple versions of bootstrap and some appears before you included the jquery.

You could try:

```
<meta charset=amp;quot;utf-8amp;quot;>
<meta http-equiv=amp;quot;X-UA-Compatibleamp;quot; content=amp;quot;IE=edgeamp;quot;>
<meta name=amp;quot;viewportamp;quot; content=amp;quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1amp;quot;>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<meta charset=amp;quot;utf-8amp;quot;>
<meta http-equiv=amp;quot;X-UA-Compatibleamp;quot; content=amp;quot;IE=edgeamp;quot;>
<meta name=amp;quot;viewportamp;quot; content=amp;quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1amp;quot;>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```