# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery after upgrading the jquery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I had `jquery-2.2.x` earlier and code was running fine. Now, I have updated the `jquery-3.3.x` and started getting the error `datepicker()` function doesn't exist. After searching about that error, came to know that it need `moment.js` and `bootstrap.js`. So after adding these package, I am getting the error :
`Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Although I'm importing the `jquery`.

This code is running without any error when I am using `jquery-2.2.x`, but the same code with `jquery-3.3.x` is not working and giving error `datepicker()` function is not defined.

```
const React = require('react');
const $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css');
require('bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js');
require('styles/InputField.css');
/*
    Renders a single input field with label and inputBox
    Attributes
    1)labelText -> text for the label
    2)inputId -> Id for the input box
    3)inputPlaceholder -> placeholder for the input
    4)isDate -> if the field is for date activate the jquery datepicker
    Returns a div
*/
class InputField extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            datepickerEnabled: false
        }
    }

    // If the component is mounted and it is a date field activate the datepicker
    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.isDate === 'true') {
            $('#' + this.props.inputId).datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
            this.setState({
                datepickerEnabled: true
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor={this.props.inputId}> {this.props.labelText} </label>
                <input type='text' id={this.props.inputId} placeholder={this.props.inputPlaceholder} className='form-control'/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = InputField;
```

Comment: why would you need moment.js? Are you sure that you maybe only need jquery-ui? Can you create a problem here that shows your problem? eg the created HTML and all JS that is imported.

Comment: @cloned updated the question with full code

Comment: Maybe check [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658015/bootstrap-throws-uncaught-error-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery)?

Comment: You don't need any additional js libraries when your code is pure jQuery, jquery and jquery-ui is enough. Have you looked at the html source code of your page and verified that there's a script tag pointing towards your jQuery files?