# JQuery not importing and console tells me I did not import the script even when I did

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, import

I got this error:

```
index.html:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.html:109
(anonymous) @ index.html:109
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

I imported JQuery but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried

```
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or even

```
<script async src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js
```

But it still doesn't work and gives me the same error!
Any suggestions for help?

Comment: Can you try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22658081/9599554

Comment: What is the order of your script when you are loading bootstrap and jQuery? jQuery should be loaded first and then bootstrap.

Comment: thx that solution worked @Vikram