# Bootstrap radio button with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**What I am trying to accomplish:**
I am trying to make a form where when a user selects yes a div slides down, and when the user selects no the div slides up (thus making what is in that div invisible). and I want this to have a nice display (to look almost like a button in a group that can toggle and only one is able to toggle at a time such as a radio button) it should look more or less like this:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups

**What my problem is:**
When I toggle this button it will not fire a function.

**Where it gets weird**
I notice that when I don't set the data-toggle="buttons" I get radio buttons that have the little circle and fire the function, but when I set data-toggle="buttons" it will not fire the function.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="questionnaire">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input class="btn btn-default" data-role="none" type="radio" value="yes" name="vomit" />yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input class="btn btn-default" data-role="none" type="radio" value="no" name="vomit" />no
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="expand">
        <h4>How many times?</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the function I am trying to fire:

```
$('#questionnaire input[name=vomit]').on('change', function () {
    var $p = $('.expand');
    if ($('input[name=vomit]:checked').val() == "yes") {
        //alert("hello");
        $p.slideDown();
    }
    else {
        //alert("nope");
        $p.slideUp();
    }
});
```

Can anyone please help me get the radio button to look like the bootstrap (and once selected they stay the color) one but that functions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have something else going on with your code? Any error messages in your browser console? I copied and pasted your code into a fiddle and it works perfectly using Jquery 2.1 and Bootstrap 3.1.1. http://jsfiddle.net/JgbLG/

Comment: Well, I see that you are correct. When I inspect it I get some errors :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:52311/Content/themes/base/css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:52311/bundles/jqueryui
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

It doesn't seems to be effecting this, That is really strange that it does this, and there are no warnings or anthing.

Comment: Are you trying to use both Jquery UI and Bootstrap in the same project? Can you remove all references to JQuery UI and see if your code starts working? Jquery UI has conflicted with bootstrap in the past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428285/bootstrap-and-jqueryui-conflict

Comment: I am using both, This could be the issue, I will have to check and get back to this. Thanks

Comment: What order are your javascript files included in? Try having your bootstrap javascript file after your JqueryUI javascript file. This should prevent JqueryUI from overwriting bootstrap functionality although on the downside, your bootstrap javascript may overwrite some of your JqueryUI events and break other areas of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this switch here :
http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/
here is the html:

```
<h4>Did you Vomit?</h4>
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="vomit"  />

  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="vomit">
  <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div> 

<div class="expand">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
  <input type="number" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the jquery

```
   $("#vomit").change(function () {
    var $p = $('.expand');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {//this is true if the switch is on
        $(this).val("Yes");
        $p.slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $(this).val("No");
        $("#numVomit").val(0);
        $p.slideUp();
    }
    });
```

It seems like there was truly a conflict with jquery, bootstrap and jquery-ui. I will have to end up doing some code cleanup to see exactly where it is conflicting.