# Responsiveness with Jquery Ui and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have my Website build with JqueryUI widgets. Now I need to make Website responsive and I was recommended by a friend to use bootstrap for this ,but i read somewhere that using both JqueryUI and Bootstrap together cause some problems or conflicts,so my  question is:-

1. Is any conflict occur ,if yes,then what kind of conflicts can occur.
2. Is there any way to avoid conflicts.
3. Any other way I can make my website responsive.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428285/bootstrap-and-jqueryui-conflict

Comment: Thanx alot @AntoKing, Yes i found solution ,Solution to use customize jquery ,bootstrap library and include their required components
but i need only CSS part of Bootstrap ,can i just include that CSS and ignore Javascript files ,will it work ?

Comment: Ya Sure you can just use CSS in case if you don't use any JavaScript components of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment suggest by me above i believe following link can be the answer [Conflicts between JQueryUI and bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428285/bootstrap-and-jqueryui-conflict)

Hope this helps...

Comment: @helped i think ,tomorrow i will try to implement same and will back to stack overflow if need help.