# jquery ui tooltip conflict with bootstrap 3 tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, tooltip

I'm using bootstrap 3 for my project layout. and also i need to jquery.ui javascript file for parts of my page. the problem is both bootstrap and jquery ui has the `tooltip` function and i want to use bootstrap tooltip, but jquery ui tooltip show up. is there any way to disable jquery ui tooltip without any effect on other jquery ui functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just include what you need from jquery-ui! Go to http://jqueryui.com/download/ and only select the things you really use (without `tooltip` obviously).

Answer (score 14):

Solution is very very easy.

```
 <script src="/js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Just load jQueryUI before loading boostrap and all will be ok!
Worked for me.

Comment: One day you will be missing close-icon in dialogs by using such approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367736/jquery-ui-dialog-missing-close-icon

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing the same issue and found a quick work around for this.

```
 <script src="/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>var bootstrapTooltip = jQuery.fn.tooltip;</script>
 <script src="/js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script>jQuery.fn.tooltip = bootstrapTooltip;</script>
```

This will override jquery-ui's tooltip and use bootstrap's tooltip.

Comment: This worked for me as I could not fiddle around with the order of script inclusion +1

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script src="/js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

is a fix which will not work for long run as UI btton or any plug in css might not work properly. Not solution.