# How to use jQuery UI Tooltip instead of Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, tooltip

The Bootstrap tooltip is overwriting `$.fn.tooltip`. How can I call `$.ui.tooltip` on my element?

For context, I'm using `PrestaShop 8` which ships with `Bootstrap 4`. I can't modify the loaded scripts.

Is there a way to still be able to use jQuery UI Tooltip?

Here's the code that I tried

```js
$.ui.tooltip(node) // this gave me an error
$.ui.tooltip.prototype._tooltip(node) // also gave an error
```

Thank you

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hp8yak0g/4/)

Comment: I think this will help you more about tooltip issue :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667223/jquery-ui-tooltip-conflict-with-bootstrap-3-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667223/jquery-ui-tooltip-conflict-with-bootstrap-3-tooltip)

Comment: @Digvijaysinhchauhan Unfortunately I can't move the scripts around. Even if I fix it locally, it won't help other shops because my script is distributed to many other shops that I can't control.