# How to force jQuery UI asset always included before Bootstrap plugin asset in Yii2?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I have a problem that appears from including BootstrapPluginAsset before JuiAsset. (Link: [Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'loading'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190437/uncaught-error-cannot-call-methods-on-button-prior-to-initialization-attempted)).

Since the `\yii\web\BootstrapPluginAsset` only have dependency to `yii\web\JqueryAsset` and `yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset` not `\yii\jui\JuiAsset` ([link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/blob/master/BootstrapPluginAsset.php#L24)), how to make sure that `\yii\jui\JuiAsset` will always be included before `yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include multiple CSS or JavaScript files in a Web page, they have to follow a certain order to avoid overriding issues. For example, if you are using a jQuery UI widget in a Web page, you have to make sure the jQuery JavaScript file is included before the jQuery UI JavaScript file. We call such ordering the dependencies among assets.

```
public $depends = [
'yii\web\YiiAsset',
'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
];
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69670-how-to-force-jquery-ui-asset-always-included-before-bootstrap-plugin-asset-in-yii2/page__view__findpost__p__295772