# Unable to change button text after jQuery success get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the text of a button, but I'm unable to do it.

```js
$( function() {
 $('.btn').on('click', function(automated_campagin_hash) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.button('loading');
        
    var automated_campagin_hash = $this.data('campaign-automated-hash');
    var url = "/automated-campaigns/change_status/" + String(automated_campagin_hash);
    $.get( url , function( data ) {
          console.log(data);
        $this.button('reset');
        $this.removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-info");
        $this.html('Activated');
    });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i>" data-campaign-automated-hash="<%= automated_campaigns[i].automated_campaign_hash %>">Desativar</button>
```

Comment: No, the problem is that it not changing to Activated

Comment: @Santi `$this` is a variable he defined at the top of his function and is assigned to `$(this)`

Comment: Is it changing the class?

Comment: Running the code in the snippet makes it pretty obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, it is changing the class. The this.button I got from this snippet: http://codepen.io/jmalatia/pen/HkmaA

Comment: Sorry, JQuery UI is included in my source code: <script src="/assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

And there is no error on loading it in console

Comment: `.button()` is a [bootstrap thing](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)

Comment: Yes, it is included too.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak It's not just a bootstrap thing, jQuery UI also has a [`.button`](http://www.tutorialspark.com/jqueryUI/jQueryUI_Button_Methods.php) method.

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano It's a pity you're using off-site resources in your code - as it's difficult for someone else to reproduce the errors you're seeing, they will be getting different ones.  Maybe you could work on creating a [mcve]

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190437/uncaught-error-cannot-call-methods-on-button-prior-to-initialization-attempted

Comment: In addition to @Tibrogargan comment, your code works for me http://jsbin.com/jojuwoleca/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Sag1v thanks, I changed the order of jquery ui and bootstrap plugins. I added jquery ui and then boostrap. Can you add an aswer and I accept it?

Comment: This question should've been closed, rather than accepted, IMO: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."* - While this answer may be a solution to many problems out there, I dont' see this question being the one they find.

Comment: @Santi I partly disagree, you may have a point but i think that this question holds much more details then other questions on this manner, even though my answer was only referencing another question, that referenced question lacks the details it needs (code snippet?). i think the OP of this question should include the `bootstrap` link tag to the snippet and that will get this question the ability to reproduced while running the snippet and include a broader picture.

Comment: If OP edited the entire question to warrant the answer he's accepted, then sure. But that's what "Retract Close Vote" is for. There are certainly changes that could make this question work better, however as it stands, they aren't there - thus, I believe in it's *current form*, it should be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mentioned you are using bootstrap as well (though it's not referenced in your snippet).
so here is a possible solution quoted from [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31271623/3148807)

> It's caused by jquery-ui and bootstrap-button plugins conflict. In fact jquery-ui code js code should go before bootstrap.js, and that solves the problem.
>   Just put jquery-ui plugins before bootstrap.js

Comment: I believe it's because you're answering the question by copy/paste someone's answer without adding anything new. You should mark the question as a duplicate if it was already asked and answered.