# Show 'Close' Button in jQuery UI - Dialog Box with WP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a dialog box using `jquery ui dialog` in wordpress. The problem that I am having is when the dialog box appear, the close button `'X'` is not shown. example as below.

[image]

I have make some reading regarding this issue and it is due to conflict on `bootstrap`. [Reference on Stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457891/5594649) How do I want to implement it on wordpress? Below are my codes on `functions.php` that I made

```
function add_my_script() {     
   if(is_page('my_custom_page')){
     //Tried to deregister bootsrap and it work fine but I need the boostrap as well. 
     //wp_deregister_script('zerif_bootstrap_script');
     //Tried to degregister and enqueue back the script to follow the rules base on reference  
     //wp_enqueue_script('zerif_bootstrap_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '20120206', true);
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
   }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script');
```

> Update Solutions:

Currently I am using **Zerif Lite** on my theme and it is on `function.php`.

```
wp_enqueue_script('zerif_bootstrap_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '20120206', false);
```

The default value is `true` that will be place in **footer**. I change the value to false so that it will be place in the header as same as my jquery-ui scripts.

Comment: Hello Amran, `jQuery` uses icons image, it should be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening, is because you are calling `bootstrap` in, after you are calling `jquery-ui` in.

swap the two so that instead of:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

it becomes

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

after that it works fine.

Comment: Thanks  for the help. Do I need to `deregister`  my bootstrap script first? How to implement it with wordpress? Sorry, I am still learning on wordpress :)

Comment: Just change the order and hard reload the page.

Comment: On my `functions.php`, I am unable to find the script for `jquery-ui.js` to replace it. Do I need to add it on my `header.php` or I can add the script on `functions.php`

Comment: Search it in page by inspecting the page. And if it is present in header then open the header.php and if it is last the open the footer.php

Comment: Found it! Thanks @MayankPandeyz for the details

Comment: Sounds great !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143750/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-amran).