# Jquery UI don't work well with bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have a jquery UI DataPicker inside my bootstrap3 model . when i triggle the modal . the DataPicker can show correctly . and i could pick the data as well . but when i click down either the month selecter or the year selecter .and pick an option. it will dimiss the modal and the DatePicker will leave on the page alone still .

 here is my Html code :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target   ="#myModal">
              DatePicker
           </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
                <input type='text' class='datepicker' >
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

js code :

```
 $(".datepicker").closest(".modal").css("z-index") 
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({

    changeMonth: true,

    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    currentText: "This Month",
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
        $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm', new Date(year, month - 1, 1)));
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var month = $(".ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm', new Date(year, month, 1)));
    }
}).focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
}).after(
    $("<a href='javascript: void(0);'>clear</a>").click(function() {
        $(this).prev().val('');
    })
);
```

i've test the z-index of datapicker ,that don't work for me ...

here is the js Bin [1]:http://jsbin.com/uhizoRA/52/edit

Comment: The [datepicker conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9048214/586086) is one of the biggest issues in combining bootstrap and jQuery UI.

Comment: yeah , but i've fixed this problem . :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have figured out by myself ...

first i've listen for the hide event .

```
 $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {

    if(event.target instanceof HTMLDivElement)
      {
        return false; 
      }
        // alert(event.target);
       return true; // validate before show the modal
  })
```

and check what has triggled the event , then do a comparision.

Note: typeof could only return limit object type :

```
Type    Result
Undefined   "undefined"
Null    "object"
Boolean "boolean"
Number  "number"
String  "string"
Host object (provided by the JS environment)    Implementation-dependent
Function object (implements [[Call]] in ECMA-262 terms) "function"
E4X XML object  "xml"
E4X XMLList object  "xml"
Any other object    "object"
```

so , if u wanna check the type of an specifiec object , use the `instanceof` method .