# How to center the dialog title, button and how center JQuery dialog box after browser resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css

the issue I am having is that I am able to create the dialog fine with links and center the text inside the dialog. I am not able to do that with the title and with the button. Another issue I am having is for some reason, the button I have created appears on the dialog box but is not functional and I have tried to center my JQuery dialog box after browser resize but I have failed with that as well. I would like to know how I can fix the issue. Any help would be appreciated thank you all in advance. The following is jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/robontrix/194Ljr30/

HTML:

```
       <div id="dialog">            
          <p style="text-align:center"> Your computer use can be monitored by others! Consider using a public computer or a friend's computer. Please view more computer safety tips or escape to Google. Then more computer safety tips linked to a page with details about browser history, cache, search history, etc. and escape to Google linked to Google.</p>
          <p style="text-align:center"> To learn more how to computer safety, click the following link: <br><a href="#">Safety Tips</a></br></p>
          <!--Wording can be better just for the meantime-->
          <p style="text-align:center"> If you are not safe, click the following link: <br><a href="#">Get Me Out of Here!</a></br></p> 
        </div> 

        <!--JQuery -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

        <script>
            $('#dialog').attr('title','Safety Warning!').dialog({
             width : 700,
             height: 350,
             modal:true,
             opacity:.7,
             closeOnEscape: true, 
             draggable: false, 
             resizable: false,
             buttons: { "Close": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                }
             }
            });
            $(window).resize(function() {
              $('#dialog').dialog('option','position', 'center');
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I see you've edited the question with more code. One thing that definitely is wrong in the currently posted code is you are loading 2 different jquery frameworks.

Comment: Also, unless you are omitting some stylesheets you have already written for this, you should consider starting with including the jquery.ui.css - this would make my answer work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can center the button and titlebar with CSS (assuming you are loading the jquery-ui css - your question doesn't clarify if you are or not - see update below):

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: none;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title, .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    text-align:center;
    padding-left: 0.4em;
    padding-right: 0.4em;
}
```

As for the button not working, something else must be causing that. If the button isn't even clickable, then maybe you have some other element with a z-index interfering in the DOM.

Edit: [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwells/95bhod8h/1/)

Again, this assumes you are loading the jquery-ui CSS. If you aren't, you can try adding just the CSS for the dialogs by adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css">
```

Comment: but he didn't include it in that link?

Comment: True. Not a great use of jsfiddle since it was basically just the code that he originally posted in the question (before the edit).

Comment: I have tried using that and I plugged it in the CSS file but it didnt seem to work at all. Also, thank you for your guys help. I will try to do it and see what I am doing wrong

Comment: The button is clickable but the issue is nothing happens. It doesnt close the dialog box, so I am wondering if I needed to add back the $function() before using Dialog()

Comment: Here's an updated fork of your jsfiddle that works... note the usage of jQuery and jQuery UI in the fiddle options. https://jsfiddle.net/cwells/95bhod8h/1/

Comment: and what do you mean by loading jquery-ui css? I am still new to developing and I am currently using bootstrap for the responsive side. So, would me loading jquery-ui css conflict with bootstrap?

Comment: There may be conflicts - that's up to you to find out - I don't know Bootstrap (nor did I know you were using that).  But now that I know, you may want to look into using [Bootstrap's Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) instead of jquery ui dialog.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20460093/584599) for more information regarding using jquery ui and bootstrap together.

Comment: I know this might be a dumb question, but I do not see the difference in code. Do I need to create a js file for it to work correctly?

Comment: Difference in code where? Have you tried adding the jquery-ui css? You can try just adding the css for the jquery dialogs with <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css"> above your own CSS...

Comment: Above my CSS? You mean add this into my index.html file?

Comment: Yes. are you loading any other CSS files on the page?  Put that line (now included at the bottom of my answer) just before any custom CSS you are loading or declaring inline on the page. See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Yes, there are other CSS files that I have done. I have added the link based on the howto and it still does not work correctly

Comment: Couple things - you are still loading 2 different version of jquery. Actually... you are loading 3 different versions. You only need one. Second, I can't tell from that codeshare that you've also included the css I provided in my answer. Also, since you are trying to load a jquery dialog, you need to load the jquery-ui library as well. Please see http://jqueryui.com/ - again, you may be better off just using bootstrap's modal instead, since it's built-in.