# is it compatible to use at the same time jquery-ui and bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

is it compatible to use at the same time jquery-ui and bootstrap?

I am trying to use dialog of jquery ui and inside biootstrap, And I would like to know the compatibility because I am new in bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048214/can-i-use-twitter-bootstrap-and-jquery-ui-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. Yes :)

They are compatible for the most part. Some styling clashes may require you to tweak control sizes.