# Bootstrap 4 datepicker with JqueryWidgets

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to have a properly styled boostrap 4 datepicker with jquery widgets.

```
    <input class="form-control" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="date" id="datepicker">
```

Javascript:

```
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        allowInputToggle: true,
         uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'

    });
```

> Screenshot below of the datepicker.

[image]

Comment: How do you mean 'properly styled'? Do you mean just not overlapping the other datepicker?

Comment: Why not just use the bootstrap one?

Comment: @NathanielFlick I am using the Jqxwidget grid

Comment: @Shiny it shouldnt be clear with blue numbers

Comment: @Curious-programmer your question doesn't make sense. Do you want to style the jQuery picker with bootstrap styles?

Comment: @NathanielFlick  No I want to use the bootstrap datepicker, with  boostrap style but the jquery widget base css, which I am using for other widgets appears to conflict unless there is some other issue

Comment: MIght be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048214/can-i-use-twitter-bootstrap-and-jquery-ui-at-the-same-time